# How to filter on year and quarter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column of type datetime64[ns]. I want to filter on both year and quarter. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I have tried this cumbersome solution

```
data = data[(pd.Series(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['MatCalID']).year).isin([2018]) & pd.Series(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['MatCalID']).quarter).isin([2,3]))]
```

Why this complicated solution?:

- It is necessary to use pd.DatetimeIndex in order to access 'year' and 'quarter'
- It is necessary to use pd.Series to use 'isin'

Unfortunately I get 'Unalignable boolean Series key provided' as an error.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Is your version of pandas 0.15.0 or higher? if so this seems unnecessary to convert to a datetimeIndex as you can access `year` and `quarter` via `.dt` e.g. `price['MatCalID'].dt.year` also are you wanting something like `data[(price['MatCalID'].dt.year == 2008) & (price['MatCalID'].dt.quarter.isin([2,3]))]`?

Comment: Also what's the relationship between `data` and `price`? are these views of the same df? of the df's?

Comment: Thanks Ed, 'dt' works perfectly. And I meant data, not price. It has now been changed in the question.

Comment: So when you say working you mean I should post as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, you should do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running pandas version `0.15.0` or higher it is not necessary to cast the Series to a `DateTimeIndex` as there is now a new datetime attribute [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties). You can use this to access the year and quarter attributes of the datetime objects and use a boolean condition to filter the df:

```
data[(data['MatCalID'].dt.year == 2008) & (data['MatCalID'].dt.quarter.isin([2,3]))]
```

Normally you should be using `isin` when you want to test membership of multiple values rather than a single value