# How to filter a pandas series with a datetime index on the quarter and year

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a Series, called 'scores', with a datetime index.

I wish to subset it by `quarter` and `year`
pseudocode: `series.loc['q2 of 2013']`

Attempts so far:
`s.dt.quarter`

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

`s.index.dt.quarter`

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

This works (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462512/how-to-filter-on-year-and-quarter-in-pandas)), but I can't believe it is the right way to do this in Pandas:

> `d = pd.DataFrame(s)`
>   `d['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d.index)`
>   `d.loc[(d['date'].dt.quarter == 2) & (d['date'].dt.year == 2013)]['scores']`

I expect there is a way to do this without transforming into a dataset, forcing the index into datetime, and then getting a Series from it.

What am I missing, and what is the elegant way to do this on a Pandas series?

Comment: this will work if the index is datetime `s.index.quarter`.

Comment: Do you want a function that you can get at a specific year and quarter?

Comment: IIUC you need  `scores.ix[scores.index.quarter==2]`.

Comment: @shivsn has the right answer, I'm shocked I didn't think of letting go of the `dt` thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2013-01-01', freq='M', periods=12)
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(12), index=index)
print(s)

# 2013-01-31    0.820672
# 2013-02-28    0.994890
# 2013-03-31    0.928376
# 2013-04-30    0.848532
# 2013-05-31    0.122263
# 2013-06-30    0.305741
# 2013-07-31    0.088432
# 2013-08-31    0.647288
# 2013-09-30    0.640308
# 2013-10-31    0.737139
# 2013-11-30    0.233656
# 2013-12-31    0.245214
# Freq: M, dtype: float64

d = pd.Series(s.index, index=s.index)
quarter = d.dt.quarter.astype(str) + 'Q' + d.dt.year.astype(str)
print(quarter)

# 2013-01-31    1Q2013
# 2013-02-28    1Q2013
# 2013-03-31    1Q2013
# 2013-04-30    2Q2013
# 2013-05-31    2Q2013
# 2013-06-30    2Q2013
# 2013-07-31    3Q2013
# 2013-08-31    3Q2013
# 2013-09-30    3Q2013
# 2013-10-31    4Q2013
# 2013-11-30    4Q2013
# 2013-12-31    4Q2013
# Freq: M, dtype: object

print(s[quarter == '1Q2013'])

# 2013-01-31    0.124398
# 2013-02-28    0.052828
# 2013-03-31    0.126374
# Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

If you don't want to create a new Series that holds a label for each quarter (e.g., if you are subsetting just once), you could even do

```
print(s[(s.index.quarter == 1) & (s.index.year == 2013)])

# 2013-01-31    0.124398
# 2013-02-28    0.052828
# 2013-03-31    0.126374
# Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a dataframe like this:

```
sa
Out[28]: 
             0
1970-01-31   1
1970-02-28   2
1970-03-31   3
1970-04-30   4
1970-05-31   5
1970-06-30   6
1970-07-31   7
1970-08-31   8
1970-09-30   9
1970-10-31  10
1970-11-30  11
1970-12-31  12
```

If the index is datetime then you can get the quarter as `sa.index.quarter`:

```
sa.index.quarter
Out[30]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the the year and quarter, say Q2 2013, then you can do this:

```
s['2013-04':'2013-06']
```

Wrap it up into a function:

```
qmap = pd.DataFrame([
        ('01', '03'), ('04', '06'), ('07', '09'), ('10', '12')
    ], list('1234'), list('se')).T

def get_quarter(df, year, quarter):
    s, e = qmap[str(quarter)]
    y = str(year)
    s = y + '-' + s
    e = y + '-' + e
    return df[s:e]
```

and call it:

```
get_quarter(s, 2013, 2)
```

suppose `s` is:

```
s = pd.Series(range(32), pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=32, freq='Q'))
```

Then I get:

```
2013-03-31    8
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

For future-comers, just skip the `.dt` with a `DateTimeIndex` and use `s.quarter` instead of `s.dt.quarter`. The other answers are way too long for this.